# Update minimum values based on another value - MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of information, which i'm exploding it to id,code and number.

```
list ($id,$code,$num) = explode("~",$data);
```

I need to update it to MySql based on unique `code` with minimum of `num`

For suppose my first 3 requests looks like

```
id = 9267399
code = 5D:148
num = 64

id = 9267398
code = 5D:186
num = 71

id = 9267397
code = 5D:122
num = 93
```

Then my 4th,5th requests has duplicate code `5D:148` with different id's and num's.

```
id = 9267402
code = 5D:148
num = 22

id = 9267563
code = 5D:148
num = 5
```

Now i need to find `min(num)` for duplicate `code` and update that record back to mysql. My queries should look like

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET id = '9267398', num = '71' WHERE code = '5D:186' ";
$sql = "UPDATE table SET id = '9267397', num = '93' WHERE code = '5D:122' ";
$sql = "UPDATE table SET id = '9267563', num = '5' WHERE code = '5D:148' ";
```

here `5D:148` has 3 requests in which `min(num)` is 5.

I have tried finding the duplicate `code`

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($code as $c) {
    isset($temp[$c]) or $temp[$c] = 0;
    $temp[$c] ++;
}
var_dump($temp);
```

This is giving me

```
array(3) {["5D:148"]=> int(3) ["5D:186"]=> int(1) ["5D:122"]=> int(1)}
```

I'm stuck here how do i find `min(num)` and run my update query based on it

Comment: Do you want to have in the DB the minimum "num" for one "code" you ever recieved or the minimum for one script run (session)?

Comment: i need in DB. can't use sessions since there are lot of requests to be handled at a time.

Comment: For every request you should first try storing it to an array, and if it already exists then compare the num. If it is < than the previous, run your SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand me - do you want to have in the DB the minimum for one "code" you ever recieved? For example you will run your script 3 times - so you want to have "min" across all 3 script runs?

Comment: yes correct i want to have minimum across all scripts runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the array and check if num is lower then the previous one.

Example of $data array:

```
$data = array(
[0] => array('id' => 9267399, 'code' => '5D:148', 'num' => 64),
[1] => array('id' => 9267398, 'code' => '5D:186', 'num' => 71)
);
```

-

```
<?php

$array_to_add = array();

foreach($data AS $val) {

    if(array_key_exists($val['code'], $array_to_add)) {

        if((int) $val['num'] < (int) $array_to_add[$val['code']]['num']) { // Check if num is lower than the previous one
            $array_to_add[$val['code']] = $val; // If yes, overwrite code key with new values
        } 

    } else {

        $array_to_add[$val['code']] = $val; // Add values to array if code doesn't exist in array_to_add

    }

}

var_dump($array_to_add); // ARRAY TO ADD IN DATABASE

foreach($array_to_add AS $val) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($val['id']).", num = ".mysql_real_escape_string($val['num'])." WHERE code = '".mysql_real_escape_string($val['code'])."' ");

}

?>
```

Tip: Look at PDO and mysqli for better use of mysql query's.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a quite simpler solution... In fact I just tested it...

UPDATE table SET id = '9267398', num = '71' WHERE code = '5D:186' 
ORDER BY code ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: Why LIMIT 1? You suppose that code is not unique - but it is.

Answer (score 1):

So, what about this - you can run the query for all requests (you don't need to find the min in php) and finally you will have the min in DB (because of "and num > 5") - I suppose that min is integer, not varchar:

```
UPDATE table SET id = '9267563', num = 5 WHERE code = '5D:148' and num > 5
UPDATE table SET id = '9267563', num = 93 WHERE code = 'SD:122' and num > 93
etc.
```

Not so sophisticated but it should work fo you.